# Trying to create a sidebar with dropdown using the react-bootstrap package

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image]

**This is the HTML code I'm trying to convert using the react-bootstrap package**

i couldn't find any details for the sidebar like this.

```
                <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-light" id="sidenavAccordion">
                <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                    <div class="nav">
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                            Dashboard
                        </a>
                        <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Interface</div>
                        <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseLayouts" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLayouts">
                            <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-columns"></i></div>
                            Layouts
                            <div class="sb-sidenav-collapse-arrow"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseLayouts" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#sidenavAccordion">
                            <nav class="sb-sidenav-menu-nested nav">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="layout-static.html">Static Navigation</a>
                                <a class="nav-link" href="layout-sidenav-light.html">Light Sidenav</a>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

**i have partially converted it but the submenu is not working as in the image**

```
 <Navbar bg="" variant="" expand="" bsPrefix="accordion" className="sb-sidenav sb-sidenav-dark">
 <div className="sb-sidenav-menu">
 <Nav className="nav" activeKey="/home">
 <div className="sidebar-sticky"></div>
 <Nav.Item>
   <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
<Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
<Nav.Item>
   <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
</Nav.Item>
</Nav>
</div>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
   <nav class="sb-sidenav accordion sb-sidenav-light" id="sidenavAccordion">
            <div class="sb-sidenav-menu">
                <div class="nav">
                    <div class="sb-sidenav-menu-heading">Core</div>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                        <div class="sb-nav-link-icon"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></div>
                        Dashboard
                    </a>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-            expanded="false">
            Layouts
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Static Navigation</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Light Sidenav</a>
            </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

check this:https://jsfiddle.net/69x8pzmy/2/

Comment: I'm looking for the jsx using the react-bootstrap

Comment: @Nanda your code itself is not jsx because its using class instead of  className..let me know whats the requirement

Comment: I'm trying to convert the above code to jsx using the react-bootstrap package (NavBar , Nav ..etc) but for sidebar it's not working..sidebar has dropdown as shown in the picture.